# Angular build failed on heroku can't find module but works fine on local

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku, server, build

The application works fine on local but build fail on Heroku. Please find attached log.

```
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  12.x
       engines.npm (package.json):   6.x
       
       Resolving node version 12.x...
       Downloading and installing node 12.18.3...
       Bootstrapping npm 6.x (replacing 6.14.6)...
       npm 6.x installed
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       
       > fsevents@1.2.13 install /tmp/build_3c0db73a_/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents
       > node install.js
       
       
       Skipping 'fsevents' build as platform linux is not supported
       
       > fsevents@1.2.13 install /tmp/build_3c0db73a_/node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/fsevents
       > node install.js
       
       
       Skipping 'fsevents' build as platform linux is not supported
       
       > core-js@3.6.4 postinstall /tmp/build_3c0db73a_/node_modules/core-js
       > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
       
       
       > @angular/cli@9.1.12 postinstall /tmp/build_3c0db73a_/node_modules/@angular/cli
       > node ./bin/postinstall/script.js
       
       added 1468 packages in 32.281s
       
-----> Build
       Detected both "build" and "heroku-postbuild" scripts
       Running heroku-postbuild
       
       > dairy-management@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_3c0db73a_
       > ng build
```

```
Warning: Entry point '@ngmodule/material-carousel' contains deep imports into '/tmp/build_3c0db73a_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/core'. This is probably not a problem, but may cause the compilation of entry points to be out of order.
Compiling @angular/animations : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/animations/browser : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/animations/browser/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/common : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/clipboard : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/platform : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/bidi : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/collections : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/scrolling : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/drag-drop : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/common/http : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/common/http/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/keycodes : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/observers : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/a11y : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser/animations : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/forms : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/core : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/portal : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/overlay : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/form-field : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/autocomplete : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/badge : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/layout : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/bottom-sheet : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/button-toggle : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/card : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/checkbox : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/chips : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/button : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/dialog : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/text-field : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/input : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/datepicker : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/accordion : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/expansion : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/grid-list : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/icon : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/icon/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/divider : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/list : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/menu : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/progress-bar : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/progress-spinner : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/radio : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/sidenav : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/slide-toggle : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/slider : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/snack-bar : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/stepper : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/stepper : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/tabs : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/toolbar : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/tree : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/tree : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/core/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser-dynamic : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/compiler/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/common/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/router : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/router/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/service-worker : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/service-worker/config : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @auth0/angular-jwt : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @ngmodule/material-carousel : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling jw-bootstrap-switch-ng2 : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/table : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling cdk-table-exporter : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/select : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/tooltip : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/paginator : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/sort : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/table : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling mat-table-exporter : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling ngx-toastr : es2015 as esm2015
```

```
ERROR in src/app/shared/shared.module.ts:45:39 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './providers/httpconfig.interceptor'.
45 import { HttpConfigInterceptor } from './providers/httpconfig.interceptor';
```

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! dairy-management@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `ng build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the dairy-management@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.iBwsN/_logs/2020-09-07T17_56_37_094Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

Below is my package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.12",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.11",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.11",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.11",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.11",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.11",
    "@angular/service-worker": "~9.1.11",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "6.0.0",
    "@ngmodule/material-carousel": "^0.6.0",
    "jw-bootstrap-switch-ng2": "2.0.5",
    "mat-table-exporter": "^9.0.2",
    "ngx-toastr": "^13.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.9",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.11",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: So  src/app/shared/providers/httpconfig.interceptor.ts exists and exports HttpConfigInterceptor..?  Just making sure here..

Comment: yes. src/app/shared/providers/httpconfig.interceptor.ts is present and exports HttpConfigIntercepyot

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong version of ngx toastr for that version of angular https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr#dependencies

Comment: I tried changing the version for ngx-toastr. it's not working